# Extent report for cucumber 5.x

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, bdd, extentreports

I have been using extent report for my Cucumber-BDD automated tests for several years now,

After upgrading to the cucumber 5.6.0(or any 5.x) version, I have started seeing that that extent report doesn't seem to work.

Is anybody able to make the cucumber extent reports working for them, please share it

Comment: Could you please share the exact issue with us my friend?

Comment: U should look at [this](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber5-adapter)

Comment: @Grasshopper,thanks for this. It worked :)